# What is the function of the word 'happy'?

Tags: secondary-predicates

> I woke up happy today.

In the sentence, what is the function of the word 'happy', an adjective or adverb and is the verb 'woke up' considered as a linking verb?

I'd like to know some verbs that can be followed by adjectives although they are not linking verbs.

Comment: With most such adjectives we'd normally say *I woke up **feeling** sad/excited/etc.* But I think your particular example is at least partly influenced by the [Wake Up Happy](https://www.marketingweek.com/2010/05/17/hotels-com-unveils-tv-ad-inviting-consumers-to-wake-up-happy/) advertising campaign by hotels.com

Comment: It is an adjective functioning as predicative adjunct. It is predicative because it relates to a predicand, in this case "the subject "I", and an adjunct because it is an optional item in clause structure. The property of being "happy" is assigned to "I". Many people do call it a phrasal verb.